# Error deserializing data through google protocol buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am sending the following String data as String through Google Protocol Buffer:
"A,0,0,1,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,none,0.000000"

It is deserialized correctly from the client side.

But when I send this it fails to deserialize:
"X1351f5,0,0,1,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,none,0.000000"

The error line on the client is:

```
let wifiData = try Com_SO_Protocol_WifiSettings.init(serializedData: data)
```

with the proto file being the same as the server side one.

```
        struct Com_SO_Protocol_WifiSettings {
          var ssid: String {
            get {return _ssid ?? String()}
            set {_ssid = newValue}
          }
        }
```

Is there any special character on Google Protocol Buffer when sending Strings and how should I escape them?

Comment: What error are you getting when attempting to deserialize the second string? The Language Guide's [scalar types section](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) says only that the `string` type should contain `UTF-8` or `7-bit ASCII` text and cannot be longer than 2^32 bytes. Nothing about reserved characters.

Comment: Tryed again "135001"... works ; "135001f"... or "1350015"... does not.
Error is: truncated
/// The decoder unexpectedly reached the end of the data before it was
  /// expected.
  case truncated

Comment: Removing some characters after I am seing that the string seems to be too long:
"135001f5,0,0,1,0.000000,0.000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,none,0.000000" works.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the binary protobuf format? This kind of error almost always means that you've corrupted the data in transit, usually by treating it as text data - which it isn't. First check that the bytes (not text) you sent are the bytes you received. Until you have that: all bets are off.